# Folder name to combobox in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, combobox, directory

I wanted my combo box to fill in runtime by checking all directory name in a directory.

Here is my code :

```
    Private Sub EDITFORM_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Call CLEAR()
    End Sub

Private Sub CLEAR()
        qtytb.Enabled = False
        parttb.Clear()
        qtytb.Clear()
        DTCB.Items.Clear()
        MTHCB.SelectedIndex = ""
        YRCB.SelectedIndex = ""
        RadioButton2.Checked = True
        RadioButton1.Checked = True
        TextBox1.Clear()
        TextBox2.Clear()
   >>     Dim di As New DirectoryInfo("D:\DATABASE\" & Pick_Item.deptlbl.Text)
       If di.Exists = True Then
            For Each subDirectory As DirectoryInfo In di.GetDirectories()
                YRCB.Items.Add(CInt(subDirectory.Name.ToString))
            Next
        End If<<

    End Sub
```

That is my complete code to the combobox and load form
But when i debug, it just appear a messagebox with error so i dont know where exactly is my error in the code

```
"Conversion from "" string to integer is not valid"
```

[image: This is the picture of my directory]
Some thing like this. So, how can i add the folder name to my combobox? Exactly my Directories name are using Integer (Cause name it by year), if i add Directories by name(Not integer) it can. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I don't think the problem lies in the directory name being a number because GetDirectories returns the full path name, not just the subdir names. Can you show the complete code around the line with the error? I suppose it is Combobox1.Items.Add but you don't say anything about the location of the error.

Comment: I was using load, i will show on the question

Comment: Are you sure that value of `Pick_Item.deptlbl.Text` is METAL ????

Comment: Check my last answer in the update below, the errors your getting are related to your selectindex = "" statements! NOT related to your directory/folders

Comment: @RohitVyas I was sure, even i have tried change it to METAL, but thanks for your comment, i have got my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the TOP line

```
Dim folders() As String = IO.Directory.GetDirectories("D:\DATABASE\")
  For Each folder As String In folders
    Combobox1.Items.Add(folder)
  Next
```

## Update

Is there any other code which is present in the subroutine/event but is not included above? I tried it and it works fine even if the folder names are numbers

[image]

I think the problem is in these lines

```
MTHCB.SelectedIndex = ""
YRCB.SelectedIndex = ""
```

change them to

```
MTHCB.SelectedIndex = -1
YRCB.SelectedIndex = -1
```

Comment: Can you display one of your directory names please? I want to know if they has backslashes or any other 'special' characters

Comment: Listboxes and Comboboxes use integers not strings for the SELECTINDEX value and if you want to set to no selection you must use -1 (minus 1) not "" or null string or empty string.